# html - Abnormal behavior of hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have created a div in which I have put some hyperlinks. On those, I have added some styling that when I hover over them they get an underline, pretty simple. But when I try to hover over them an unusual small line appears.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/QxfNU/).

**HTML:**

```
<section id="header">
    <div id="header-links-holder">  
        <a href="#"><span>HOME</span>
        <a href="#"><span class="no-spacing">ABOUT US</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span>PORTFOLIO</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span class="no-spacing">CONTACT US</span></a>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    background-image: url(http://www.7daysinhavana.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/7days/images/commun/back_header_global.jpg);
    font-family: 'GarageGothicBlackRegular';
    word-spacing: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#header-links-holder {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#header a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.no-spacing {
    word-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Try hovering over the `HOME` link and see the result.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: try closing `</a>` after  `<a href="#"><span>HOME</span>`

Comment: I cannot replicate this.  It works fine.  However, I notice you use `0px` in several places.  Why?  That makes exactly as much sense as 0Siddiqui!  0 is 0 -- using a unit with it makes no sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo, you are not closing your `a` tag

```
<a href="#"><span>HOME</span></a>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QxfNU/3/)

Always use [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to avoid such errors and use debugging tools like [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

> Note: Also view source of your HTML documents, as far as I know,
>   Firefox will highlight stray tags in red

Comment: Thanks for that additional info as well!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
<a href="#"><span>HOME</span>
```

You forgot the closing

```
    <a href="#"><span>HOME</span></a>
```